# Linux shell easy way to count key

Tags: linux, shell

Easy way to count key
my way:

```
cat \  
public.log.2015050723  \  
public.log.2015050800  \  
public.log.2015050801  \  
public.log.2015050802  \  
public.log.2015050803  
| grep 18310680207  | wc -l
```

I need easy way to count this. In fact, my question is how does `cat` use `grep`?

File list:

```
public.log.2015050723  
public.log.2015050800  
public.log.2015050801  
public.log.2015050802  
public.log.2015050803
```

Comment: A question better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Comment: I don't understand the question here at all.

Comment: You can use: `grep -c 18310680207 public.log.*`

Comment: You don't identify what the 'key' is.  You state that you have to count 'key' and then you say you have to count 'this', and then you change your question, apparently, half way through your question. "How does cat use grep?"  It doesn't.  It is a totally different tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier because it uses one fewer processes:

```
cat public.log.2015050723  \  
    public.log.2015050800  \  
    public.log.2015050801  \  
    public.log.2015050802  \  
    public.log.2015050803  |  # Note pipe or backslash needed here!
grep -c 18310680207
```

Note that the pipe symbol needs to appear after the last file name, or you need a backslash after the last file name.

If you need the occurrences per file, then you can lose the `cat` too (which is what [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237288/linux-shell-easy-way-to-count-key/31237868#comment50472966_31237288)):

```
grep -c 18310680207 \  
    public.log.2015050723  \  
    public.log.2015050800  \  
    public.log.2015050801  \  
    public.log.2015050802  \  
    public.log.2015050803
```

You can reduce the list of file names, with your sample file names, to:

```
cat public.log.2015050723 public.log.201505080[0-3] |
grep -c 18310680207
```

or:

```
grep -c public.log.2015050723 public.log.201505080[0-3]
```